# How to make PHP-based simple managing system?

Tags: php, yii, crud

I have two tables:

```
tbl_author: authorId, name
tbl_book: bookId, authorId, title
```

What I want is to create php-based system, which is able to:

- show authors, books in a grid; support filtering & pagination;
- functionallity to add/edit/delete authors/books;
- support autocomplete for when entering a new book, so it helps to fill an author.

I can surely on it using *raw php*, but it'll take a week. Tried to use *Yii*, but it still lacks components required for auto-complete.

On the other hand this is doable in no time in MS Access starting from 1998. So I think, is there php-world solution (I mean tool or framework), to quickly create such a simple CRUD systems?

Comment: who said Yii does not support that? sql Isn't that just joins to deal with?

Comment: *Yii* supports it, but I want is to be as simple, as defining relations between tables and choosing what field to show for autocomplete for author name (e.g. tbl_author.name -> tbl_authorId).

Comment: Try **Symfony 2** with **DataTable** and other bundles that my help.

Comment: Actually i dunno what is your question is all about. If you are asking how to implement it, Yii framework as all you need.

Comment: @madi There are hundred of ways to implement it. I need *the quickest one*, like 1-2 hours for 5-6 cross-referencing tables.

Answer (score 1):

The above is just a matter of table relations and yii do support such things. I am giving my answer based on Yii1.

** A) functionallity to add/edit/delete authors/books;**

Use Yii , GII creation tool to get started

**B) show authors, books in a grid; support filtering & pagination;**

Step 1: create a relation in Author model to say Author has many Books

Step 2: Create a relation for Book to say Book has One Author

[Click here for reference](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/181/relations-belongs_to-versus-has_one/)

Step 3: Use CActiveDataProvider so that it handles pagination. Here you can use the model Book:

```
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Book', array(
    'criteria'=>array(
        'with'=>array('author'),
    ),
    'pagination'=>array(
        'pageSize'=>20,
    ),
));
```

It will return all the books linked with authors. Of coz , with the data you can display as you want. There is such a thing called CGridView.

Step 4: As for searching, you can refer [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/35722-using-model-search-to-create-dataprovider-from-controller/)

**C) support autocomplete for when entering a new book, so it helps to fill an author.**

This is the matter of jquery and search.